# Stick the footer to the bottom of the page when contents are dynamic

Tags: html, css

I have tow pages of html that contain a footer. I want to stick the footer to the bottom of the page in both pages. It works fine when the page does not have vertical scroll but when the content is a lot and page has scroll footer stands over my contents. Here is my page layout:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header"> Header </div>
        <div id="menu"> Menu </div>        
        <div id="content"> Content </div>
        <div id="footer"> Footer </div>                
    </div>
</body>
```

and here is my css:

```
html, body
{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
} 

#header, #menu, #content, #footer
{
    border:thin solid #000;
}

#content
{
    width:70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:100%;
}

#footer
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#06F;
}
```

Comment: remove `position:absolute;` on #footer

Answer (score 2):

Change your CSS like;

```
#footer{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#06F;
}
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/FwenF/)** is a working Live Demo.

and if you want the footer stick to the bottom, no matter the content is, try;

```
#footer{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#06F;
    bottom:0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

But define a `height` to your footer and add the same amount of `padding-bottom` to your content, otherwise some text may be hidden by footer

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/FwenF/1/)** is a working Live Demo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I want. The footer is fixed in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
#footer {
   background-color: #0066FF;
   width: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {background-color: #0066FF;bottom: 0;position: absolute;width: 100%;bottom:0px;}
        body,html {height:100%}
```

by this way you will get your output

Comment: this works only when your page does not have a lot of data on it. I mean it works when your page does not have vertical scroll. By the way my own css is the same.